# Running multiple SQL files in a single transaction of PostgreSQL on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file

I am trying to run multiple SQL files in a single transaction of PostgreSQL. In Linux environments this can actually be achieved by using here-document as:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d mydatabase << files
BEGIN;
\i file1.sql
\i file2.sql
commit;
files
```

But I am unable to achieve the same in Windows environment.

Comment: Put everything in a SQL script and then use `psql  .. -f commands.sql`

Comment: But i also need to have transaction in this

Comment: If the here document you have shown works in Linux, the this will also work as a single file in Windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put everything in a one file, e.g.

```
\i file1.sql
\i file2.sql
```

Then call psql with the `-f` parameter. To force a single transaction use `--single-transaction`

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -d mydatabase --single-transaction -f the_script.sql
```